# Determining progress of a transfer

Tags: mysql, percona, innobackupex

We are having a restoration system which uses [innobackupex](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/streaming_backups_innobackupex.html). I want to see the number of bytes transferred at any point of time. How can I do that?